# Efficient Pair and Select

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop

I am trying to more efficiently choose the best combination of pairs without repeats. There are two sets of 3 values, the values that are most similar should be combined, as one pair is made the value it was matched with is not left to be chosen from anymore.

> For Example - 
>   A1 - 4.3    B1 - 4.4  
>   A2 - 0.5    B2 - 2.3  
>   A3 - 2.4    B3 - 1.0

So the values that are most similar would be: A1B1, A2B3, A3B2.
The first pair made, and any other combinations of the pairs could be disregarded as each pair is selected.

> Ex - 
>   **A1B1** 0.1, **A1B2** 1.4, **A1B3** 2.0,  
>   **A2B1** 3.9, **A2B2** 1.8, **A2B3** 0.5, 
>   **A3B1** 2.0, **A3B2** 0.1, **A3B3** 1.4

The example above is a slightly simplified version of my problem, as I have 5 groups with two different values that should be the most similar, and I have about 200,000 of these groups to combine.

Currently, I have the python code similar to below that sorts each dataframe after all of the combinations possible have been created, but it is very slow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['s','group_x',1,4.3,10],['s','group_x',2,0.5,8],['s','group_x',3,2.4,43],['t','group_x',1,5.9,13],['t','group_x',2,2.0,20],['t','group_x',3,1.3,38]],columns=['info','type','group','x','y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['s','group_y',1,4.4,12],['s','group_y',2,2.3,33],['s','group_y',3,1.0,10],['t','group_y',1,2.3,21],['t','group_y',2,5.0,15],['t','group_y',3,0.9,42]],columns=['info','type','group','x','y'])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['info'], sort=False)
df['x'] = abs(df['x_x'] - df['x_y'])
df['y'] = abs(df['y_x'] - df['y_y'])

best = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df))
# for each set of combinations
for i in range(0,len(df), 8):
    # sort set by values to get closest values at top
    sett = df.loc[i:i+8].sort_values(by=['group_x','x','y']).reset_index(drop=True)
    # for each combination
    for j in range(1,3):
        # select top pair and add to best df
        best = best.append(sett.loc[0], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
        # remove best group_2 used and best group_1 already paired
        sett = sett[sett['group_y'] != sett['group_y'][0]]
        sett = sett[sett['group_x'] != j].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Overall just trying to select the best pair from the set of options without repeats.

Comment: Just to confirm, the rule is to select the closest two numbers each time then remove them from the set so if A is 1, 2, 3 and B is -1, -2, -3 you expect 1,-1 2,-2 and 3,-3?

Comment: Can you also clarify your comment about 5 groups with 2x values to compare?  Maybe give a concrete example of a couple of items.  If you were searching a single dimension, you could avoid almost all of the comparisons by sorting the lists.  If Ai < Bj, you don't need to also compare Ai to any vaules where Bx > Bj or compare Bj to any values where Ax < Ai (until one of the two is removed, then you compare it to the next in the sort order).  But this doesn't work if you have two dimensions since the nearest in one could be the furthest in another.

Comment: Yes, to go from the set of full combinations down to one example just as you show. And I can use sorting I sort by one value first then the other value. For Example - A1 1 2 B1 1 3, A2 2 4 B2 2 5. One value is more important that it is closer, the other should also be close but is less important

Comment: You should avoid using `best.append` in you loop as it regenerate a new bigger dataframe for each loop iteration! This take 60% of the time on my machine. I advise you to append the rows in a list and then call `pd.concat`. Why dit you choose 8 and not 9 for the stride for the `i`-based loop? Additionally, your code take 0.030 second on my machine (and only 0.012 second with `pd.concat`). Is it very slow?

Comment: 0-8 = 9, current time for code is 71.2 ms, with list of lists then create dataframe is 22.4 ms!

Comment: still wondering if there is a completely diffferent way of going at the problem without a double for loop

Comment: @GillianBrooks `0-8 = 9`, no, as 8 is *not* included, the encompassing loop is actually executed with 3 iterations and I think this is not what you meant to do. You probably wanted to iterate over groups, isn't it?